# Is it possible to use systemd seccomp filtering for running applications from command line?

Tags: seccomp, systemd

Example systemd unit file, what I mean by "seccomp".

```
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
ProtectKernelTunables=true
ProtectKernelModules=true
ProtectControlGroups=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateMounts=true
PrivateDevices=true
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true
RestrictRealtime=true
SystemCallArchitectures=native
RestrictNamespaces=true
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_INET
SystemCallFilter=wait4 read stat mmap rt_sigprocmask openat ioctl
```

How to use systemd unit files with seccomp is fully understood. However, can also manual invocations of programs benefit from systemd seccomp filtering?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible with systemd. Even if it were, it wouldn't be particularly useful because many libc (and other common library) initialization routines use syscalls that the program will not need afterwards. Your best bet is to patch the programs, or hook them with `LD_PRELOAD` to enable a custom seccomp filter after everything has been initialized properly. At the very minimum, you can hook `__libc_start_main`. There is Google's [minijail](https://github.com/google/minijail) which can provide some protection, though.